# Как сделать скриншот Java Swing программой?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Программа в java swing генерирует картинку, которая должна быть сохранена в файле png/jpg. Это не 1 скриншот, таких картинок сотни, и я хочу сделать программу которая будет сама сохранять изображение с JFrame в какой-нибудь папке

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса.
В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Если вас интересует окно выбора папки для сохранения - то это [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Для получения скриншота можно использовать метод [`Robot::createScreenCapture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)), который возвращает `BufferedImage` для заданного прямоугольника `Rectangle` *(курсор мыши не будет присутствовать)*
- Получить координаты прямоугольника можно при помощи метода [`Toolkit::getScreenSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize())
- Для сохранения `BufferedImage` в виде картинки требуемого формата можно использовать метод [`ImageIO::write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,java.lang.String,java.io.File))
- Для отдельного `JFrame` можно взять его координаты `JFrame::getBounds`

Вариант решения:

```java
public static void saveScreenshot(String pngFilename) throws IOException {
    saveScreenshot(pngFilename, new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
}

public static void saveFrameImage(String pngFilename, JFrame frame) throws IOException {
    saveScreenshot(pngFilename, frame.getBounds());
}


private static void saveScreenshot(String pngFilename, Rectangle rect) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(rect);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(pngFilename));
}
```